# How can I add a new column based on NA values of another column?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I need to create a new column in R based some conditions of columns having NA values and the values of other columns.

I tried the following code for example:

```
expr1 <- data.frame(from =c("S01", "S02"),to1= c("S02", "S03"),tel=c(123,456))

expr2 <- data.frame(from =c("S01", "S04"),to2= c("S02", "S05"),post=c('ABC','XYZ'))



exp <- full_join(expr1, expr2,by="from") 

exp
```

Now I want to create a new column called to which could give the values me a new column:

Like column called 'to' with values S02 S03 S05. so 'to' is something like

```
ifelse(is.na(exp$to1)== TRUE,exp$to=exp$to2 , exp$to=exp$to1)
```

Comment: See `?dplyr::coalesce`. Also `is.na(exp$to1)` will return T/F no need to do `is.na(exp$to1)==TRUE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to select only from two column here are some options.

In base R, you could use `ifelse`

```
exp$to <- with(exp, ifelse(is.na(to1), to2, to1))

#  from  to1 tel  to2 post  to
#1  S01  S02 123  S02  ABC S02
#2  S02  S03 456 <NA> <NA> S03
#3  S04 <NA>  NA  S05  XYZ S05
```

Using `dplyr`, you can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
exp %>%
  mutate(to = case_when(is.na(to1)~to2, 
                        TRUE ~to1))
```

or `coalesce`

```
exp %>% mutate(to = coalesce(to1, to2))
```

---

However, if you have multiple `"to"` columns to select from and don't want to individually write if else condition for each one we can select the `to_cols` using `grep` and using `max.col` get the first non-NA value for each row.

```
to_cols <- grep("^to", names(exp))
exp$to <- exp[to_cols][cbind(seq_len(nrow(exp)), 
          max.col(!is.na(exp[to_cols]), ties.method = "first"))]
```

**data**

Life would be much simpler if you add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your `data.frame` creation

```
expr1 <- data.frame(from =c("S01", "S02"),to1= c("S02", "S03"),
                    tel=c(123,456), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
expr2 <- data.frame(from =c("S01", "S04"),to2= c("S02", "S05"),
                    post=c('ABC','XYZ'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
exp <- full_join(expr1, expr2,by="from")
```